# Codes in Sublime Text 2 and 3 are not in order

Tags: html, format, sublimetext3, sublimetext2

[image]

[image]

As the image above, formats for html and css suddenly became like this after I opened my sublime text 2 and 3, I can't even click ENTER. At first, this happened on my Sublime Text 2 so I uninstalled it 2x then when it doesn't work, I installed Sublime Text 3, but as you can see, problem is still there. Help.

I didn't uninstall nor accessed its files so I don't know what is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have somehow accidentally hit <kbd>F9</kbd>, which is the shortcut for "Sort Lines". You must have then saved the files so that they showed up like that every time they were opened.

It's a pain, but you'll have to re-enter the contents of those files again, because they were saved and there's no backup.

Comment: Thank you! Now my codes are working again. :D